# create sub folders from specific characters of a file in linux

Tags: bash, rename, subdirectory

I have a files with the below format `test_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv`

```
test_20200328223607.csv
test_20190523112250.csv
test_20180201065548.csv
```

I need to rename file then create a path from its name then add it to the created path with this format `2020/03/28/223607.csv`

Example:
`test_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv` =>
`mkdir YYYY/MM/DD` from filename then `rename` file to be `HHMMSS.csv` and add it to `YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm a bit confused by your use of '>>'. That has a specific meaning in bash that doesn't fit the context. Can you explain or maybe rewrite to be clearer?

Comment: @Cyrus what happened to your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an earlier answer by @Cyrus:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# define a regular expression for use with the `[[` conditional command later on to match filename patterns
re='^test_(....)(..)(..)(......)\.csv$'

# iterate through all csv files in the current directory
for i in *.csv; do
  # if filename does not match the regular expression, move on to the next loop iteration
  [[ "$i" =~ $re ]] || continue
  # the [[ conditional command leaves match results behind in an array variable named BASH_REMATCH

  # create a directory path using results; nop if directory already exists
  mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

  # ... and relocate the file to the (newly created) directory whilst giving it a new name
  mv "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/${BASH_REMATCH[4]}.csv"
done
```

Comment: can you please explain this script

Comment: @AhmedAmer I added inline comments

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks so much

Comment: is there is away to make re go through different file names like test fest dest

Comment: Sure you can replace `^test_...` with `^(test|fest|dest|foo)_...`, but you'll have to change all of the `BASH_REMATCH[n]` references with `BASH_REMATCH[n+1]` to account for the extra parentheses also doing a match.

Comment: Amazing Thanks so much rtx 13

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut to get substrings and extract the directory names that way. There may be a cleaner solution but something like this should work

```
for i in *.csv
do
  # split the string
  IFS='_'
  read -ra ADDR <<< "$i"

  year=$(echo "${ADDR[1]}" | cut -c1-4)
  ... get other sub strings ...
  path=${year}/${month}/etc
  mkdir -p "$path"
  mv "$i" "${path}"/"${seconds}".csv
done
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/